# How to show custom object tabs in Customer Portal?

Tags: customer-portal, permissions, custom-object

What are ALL the steps to show custom object tabs in Customer Portal? Some steps which I have tried are:

1. Checked the `Available for Customer Portal` checkbox in the `Custom Object Definition Detail` page.
2. Tried to edit the profile to give read access to the object, but the checkbox can't be checked, as shown:
   [image: Editing Custom Object Permissions in High Volume Customer Portal Profile]

   Please tell me all the steps required. I am using High Volume Customer Portal Profile, on Salesforce Developer Edition.

Comment: I have found and answered my own question.

Comment: Was it that you can't edit standard profiles - only custom ones?

Comment: Yes @AdamTorman, you can't edit standard profiles; you can only edit custom profiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to **clone** *High Volume Customer Portal* profile, and then you can grant permission for that object. You can't edit a Standard Profile.

See [here](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Force-com-Sites-Site-com/Cannot-edit-Custom-Object-Permissions-for-profile-authenticated/td-p/346689).